# how add new test suite from Visual Studio Testing Center application

Tags: tfs

How can i add new test suite in Visual studio  Testing center application. There is some test suite cases like  `end-to-end tests`  in test suite.

Comment: What do you mean with the Visual Studio Testing Center application? Do you mean Microsoft Test Manager (2010)?

Comment: yes,in test tab int Test Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found how to add new test cases.

[image: try to add test suite case]

Then i found that, test suite cases are adding from  "**Plan**" tab.

[image: adding test suite cases from plan tab]